# Create multiple Excel rows from Date Frequency?

Tags: excel, date

My Spreadsheet contains rows of financial transactions.  Each row contains a cell called `Frequency`.  Currently it's a text field designating if the transaction is *monthly, semi-annually, quarterly or annually.*

For example, `row 1` is a *5,000* withdrawal taking place on the *10TH OF Jan,Apr,Jul, Oct.*

Is there any function which could automatically turn the *1 row into 4 separate rows* denoting each quarterly date?

The frequency field could be in any format needed to accomplish this.  The ultimate goal is a spreadsheet sorted by date that would show all transactions for the year.  Thanks.

Comment: There is no function that will do that.  However, we can help you with VBA code that you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A cell called "Frequency" ? Is this a named range? Show some data, expected outcome and where your current efforts are at.

Answer (score 0):

You might search through [Excel functions (alphabetical)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188) but there are hundreds so it could take, and waste, a lot of time because there is no such function.

The result you seek should be relatively easy with VBA or similar.